# How can i delete space between labels in html?

Tags: html

So I have this code:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('profile') }}" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <label for="files" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Cambiar foto de perfil</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" name="photo" type="file" required>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*">
    <label for="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Actualizar</label>
    <button style="visibility:hidden;" id="submit" type="submit"> Actualizar </button>
</form>
```

I would like to know how to eliminate the space between these labels. I have tried with Margin="0" and nothing happened.....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the space to the right of "Cambiar foto de perfil"? If so, that's due to the adjacent input being styled with visibility: hidden. If you want that input to be hidden AND not take up any space, you would need to set it to Display: none instead of the visibility property.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to achieve - assuming you want to have  a form with 3 lines of input widgets, 2 file uploaders and a submit button, you may want to start off with something along these lines:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('profile') }}" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <div>
        <label for="files" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Cambiar foto de perfil:</label>
        <input id="files" style="visibility:visible;" name="photo" type="file" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
        <label for="images" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Cambiar el fichero del fotos:</label>
        <input id="images" type="file" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Actualizar:</label>
        <button style="visibility:visible;" id="submit" type="submit"> Actualizar </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Modifications in above code snippet:

- Wrap each widget and its label in a `div` element.
- Make the widgets visible
- Add a label for the image uploader

Further suggestions:

- Add a full-fledged css layout (flex or grid) to align widgets and labels.
- Add Css styles to the divs and toggle the `display` property to selectively add or remove widgets ( beware, usually considered bad user interface design ).

The [MDN Web Docs (previously Mozilla Developer Network, MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/) is an excellent resource for learning about web technologies. You may want to hav a look at [the CSS section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS]), in particular the [CSS layout tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout).